# Remove this "glare" with CSS on jQuery UI accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using a basic accordion with jQuery UI and I was wondering how can I remove that "glare" which appears when I click on the accordion tab:
[image: glare]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS: `outline: none;`

It's something the browser adds to elements that have focus.

Comment: I did some investigation into something similar a while back and just want to add that, with saved inputs (saved usernames and passwords), Chrome overrides any background and makes it impossible for you to change it (even making the selector as specific as possible and using the dreaded `!important` keyword). Turns out if you use JavaScript to set the value to the current value (yes, I mean `input.value = input.value` or something similar) then it gets rid of the background, I believe.